# How to skip an Elementary update? Conflicts with same name app

Tags: updates, system, file-management

I installed the loki app which is the best minimalist viewer today (it can display gif/jpg *and* webm files, no other viewer can). [https://lowkeyviewer.com/ if you want to ckeck it out]

However now Elementary wants to install this update:

***loki MCMC linkage analysis on general pedigrees Version: 2.4.7.4-10***

This conflicts with the app that's why I uninstalled that "loki MCMC linkage whatever it is" first.

I'm happy to skip updates forever, no way I'm giving up such a good viewer.

What can I do? Is there any other alternative? Can I change the name of the loki viewer to something else? I'm not a developer, I only cloned the git hub, run yarn and installed the loki .deb

Comment: By the way, I have reported this issue to the developer.

Comment: How did you install the application? Depending on the method, you should be able to "pin" your installed version so that it is not replaced.

Comment: Hi @matigo I just used the gdebi installer and installed the .deb file. I had to uninstall the "loki MCMC linkage analysis on general pedigrees" using synaptics. thanks for your suggestion, going to explore it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by locking the package. First in Synaptic by locking the package. Then in the Terminal with:

```
sudo apt-mark hold loki
```

Then again with `dpkg` for good measure:

```
echo "loki hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Now I can run all Elementary updates and my LowKey Viewer works like a dream. This solution is based on [this Linux Uprising post](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/how-to-keep-package-from-updating-in.html).